# Derby Pool ping fails with java.net.ConnectException in Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ubuntu-14.04

I`m just installed a Glassfish 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to ping DerbyPool but it fails with java.net.ConnectException.

> Ping Connection Pool failed for DerbyPool. Connection could not be
>   allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to
>   server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused. Please
>   check the server.log for more details.

server.log:

> [2015-01-02T20:51:12.361+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING]
>   [test.connection.pool.failed]
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service]
>   [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis:
>   1420224672361] [levelValue: 900] [[   RAR8054: Exception while
>   creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ DerbyPool ],
>   Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException :
>   Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message
>   Connection refused.]]
>
> [2015-01-02T20:51:12.366+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] []
>   [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=40
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1420224672366] [levelValue: 1000] [[   RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE. 
>   endpoint =
>   'http://`localhost`:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json';
>   attrs = '{id=DerbyPool}']]

The same problem is occurring on another computer with Glassfish 4.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess you didn't start the Derby server.

To start it, go to the command line and navigate to a folder where you can run `asadmin` (probably something like `/glassfish/bin`) and run the following:

```
asadmin start-database
```

Then try pinging again.

Comment: Hey, I get error ```RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).]]``` alot and my production CPU goes high.

I am not using this derby pool but still get this error sometimes. How to solve?