# JNDI lookup failed for the resource

Tags: jpa, glassfish, persistence.xml

I want to programm some simple JPA test. My project structure is

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── guest
        │       ├── GuestDao.java
        │       ├── Guest.java
        │       ├── GuestRest.java
        │       └── Rest.java
        └── resources
            └── META-INF
                └── persistence.xml
```

`persistence.xml` is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
<persistence-unit name="guestDB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/guestDB</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However, if I deploy on glassfish 5, using `asadmin deploy target/joe.war`, I get

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: 
Exception while deploying the app [joe] : 
JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [guestDB], Lookup: [jdbc/guestDB], Type: [javax.sql.DataSource]. 
Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.
```

The server log tells me:

```
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: guestDB not found
...
```

But I think, because of

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
```

in `persistence.xml`, I do not have to create the DB, nor any connection pool.

However, if I create a JDBC Resource, like in the following picture

[image]

I get `connection refused` error

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server localhost auf Port 1.527 mit Meldung Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt (Connection refused).
Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Okay, you might say, "use an IDE like Netbeans", but I'm trying to get the basics, so that's not an option for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to start the database:

```
asadmin start-database
```

see:

[Can't deploy my project on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279142/cant-deploy-my-project-on-glassfish)

and

[Derby Pool ping fails with java.net.ConnectException in Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747479/derby-pool-ping-fails-with-java-net-connectexception-in-glassfish)